# How to Transpose Columns to Rows and add redundant data

Tags: excel, transpose, powerquery

I'm trying to find a solution in Power Query to transpose Table 1 into Table 2 (in the link). I have seen other transpositions on this forum but not one quite like this where I need redundant data to be added. Does anyone know a way to do this type of transposition using Power Query or Excel in general?

How can I transpose Table 1 to look like Table 2?

[image]

Looking for suggestions...

Comment: Can use EXCEL VBA?  What have you try so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "add redundant data"?.  What have you tried and what have been your results?

Answer (score 0):

In the Query Editor, select the columns for your stores and then on the Transform tab of the ribbon, select Unpivot Columns > Unpivot only the selected columns.

Here is a snip of a data table (blue) and the unpivoted result below (yellow).

[image: Unpivoted Table Before and After]